# Django urls having N number of optional parameters

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to have same url pattern as [khanacademy.org](http://khanacademy.org) have in its videos. Suppose I opened a video having title "The Beauty of Algebra" its url will be http://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/introduction-to-algebra/v/the-beauty-of-algebra.

It shows three level of categories (math, algebra and introduction to algebra) in url. The same I want in django. Level of categories(no. of parameters) may increase up to N.

I didn't want to hard code the Urls like

```
url(r"^(?P<level_one>[a-zA-Z]+)/v/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$", "my_view", name="level_one"),
url(r"^(?P<level_one>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<level_two>[a-zA-Z]+)/v/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$", "my_view", name="level_two"),
url(r"^(?P<level_one>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<level_two>[a-zA-Z]+)/(?P<level_three>[a-zA-Z]+)/v/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$", "my_view", name="level_three"),
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to have a variable number of parameters in your `urls.py`. The best option may be to have a single generic catch-all url that points to a view where you write your own url dispatcher which is more complicated than what django's urls can provide.

You'd be able to parse the path and handle N number of levels within your view.

Comment: and don't foget to put your catch-all urls at the bottom of your urlpattern.